# ios/xcode/objective-c: swap uilabel for uitextfield based on internet connection

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, hidden

For a settings page, I would like to show either an editable textfield if Internet access is available or else a uilabel if there is no Internet.

I know how use .hidden element to hide and show elements e.g.

```
[label1 setHidden:YES];
```

but I don't know how to put label and textfield in same position.

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create a textfield and enable/disable it while internet is on/off.

You should create a textfield in viewDidLoad or any other function.

```
//create a textfield
UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

After Creation

```
if (<internet is on>) {
    //some code
    textField.enabled = YES;
}
else {
    //some code
    textField.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't a textfield have a rounded rectangle around the text?  Ideally would like just the text.

Comment: @user12345 Not necessarily, you can set `[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];` but this should be the default anyway :)